# Make the canvas stretch to fill the window

Tags: html, css, canvas, height

When I set the height to 100% a vertical scroll shows up in the browser. How can I stretch the canvas to 100% height without the scroll?

```
<style>        
    html, body
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    canvas
    {
        background: purple;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you setting the height to 100% as mentioned in the description or 300px as in the code?

Comment: when I change the 300px to 100% the scroll shows

Comment: I am not getting any scroll, which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Opera, what browser did you use?

Comment: I am trying on chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set **overlow:hidden** on body and you should be fine.

```
html, body
{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
canvas
{
    background: purple;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```